# Skype system tray icon size smaller than others on Ubuntu 18.04 with KDE installed

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, skype

I've decided migrate to KDE from gnome finally. I use pure Kubuntu on my home copmuter, but at work I've decided just to install kubuntu-desktop.
Everything seems to be well, except my favorite app... Skype. 
On the screenshot bellow you can see that skype icon is smaller. This is not a problem for a pure Kubuntu.
There was a bug back in early KDE 5 with tray icon sizes, but seems like it's not an issue anymore.
I've tried to remove gnome-shell and some config files in user's home directory:
`rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*`

Is there a way to fix this? 
[image]

**Update:**

Here is how skype icon look like on my home computer:
[image]

But, I've notice an interesting thing -- the icons in hover are pixelized.
On my work computer Skype icon seems to be OK in the hover, so I'm not sure now where the problem is.
[image]
[image]

Comment: But where did you find *kde-desktop*?

Comment: @DKBose what do you mean where did I find? In repos.

Comment: I think he means `kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Also I don't see any screenshot.

Comment: @KristopherIves Yes, I first tried `apt search kde-desktop` and got nothing. But I'm on KDE neon now. Then, I looked [here as well](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=kde-desktop). So the poster should clarify. Anyway, I prefer a clean install of the distro that provides the preferred DE rather than making chimeras. Problem-solving can be trickier.

Comment: @DKBose I've realized that there was a typo. Yes, I've meant kubuntu-desktop.

Comment: @KristopherIves my bad, was in a hurry a little bit. Fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like there is a bug, or maybe a several ones. 
Found opened issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/2230